# SQL Server  2005 I am not able to read from a table

Tags: sql-server-2005

Please suppose that in SQL Server 2005, if you launch the following query:

```
SELECT CHICKEN_CODE FROM ALL_CHICKENS WHERE MY_PARAMETER = 'N123123123';
```

you obtain:

```
31
```

as result.

Now, I would like to write a function that, given a value for `MY_PARAMETER`, yields the corresponding value of `CHICKEN_CODE`, found in the table `ALL_CHICKENS`.

I have written the following stored function in SQL Server 2005:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[determines_chicken_code]
(
    @input_parameter                         VARCHAR 
)
RETURNS varchar
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @myresult varchar

    SELECT @myresult  =  CHICKEN_CODE
    FROM dbo.ALL_CHICKENS
    WHERE MY_PARAMETER = @input_parameter

    RETURN @myresult
END
```

But if I launch the following query:

```
SELECT DBO.determines_chicken_code('N123123123')
```

it yields:

```
NULL
```

Why?

Thank you in advance for your kind cooperation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define the length of your varchar variables like this

```
varchar(100)
```

Without the `100` (or whatever length you choose) its lengh is `1` and the  `where` clause will filter out the correct results.

Answer (score 2):

Specify a length for your varchar (ex.: varchar(100)). Without length, varchar = 1 char.

Answer (score 1):

As per other PS, You can store only one char in the @myresult because you have not specified any length, bcoz 1 char length is default for Varchar datatype.

**Why we are getting NUll, not the first char:**

If there are multiple records are filtered on basis of `Where` clause in ALL_CHICKENS table then the value of CHICKEN_CODE column is picked up from last row in ALL_CHICKENS  table.

It seems that the last row has null value in CHICKEN_CODE  column.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a length for @input_parameter, @myresult as by default varchar lengh is 1.